# Howler doesn't play without Live server

Tags: javascript, howler.js

I created an app which uses howler to play a sound after clicking a play button. It works correctly when I open the the app using live server but it doesn't work when I open the index.html locally, by simple double click on file's icon.

Can anyone help me with it? I need to find out why it doesn't work.

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['//ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/car--_gb_1.mp3'],
  html5: true,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are omitting the URL scheme (often http or https) from your source and open the local file with the `file://` scheme, your browser will most likely try to look for the mp3 file from your local file system.

You could try adding the proper URL scheme (`http://` or `https://`) to the beginning of your source, as shown below:

```
var sound = new Howl({
  src: ['http://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/car--_gb_1.mp3'],
  html5: true,
});
```

Comment: It solved the problem. Thank you for the explanation.